# Orbit space for a nice action

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Consider the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $\mathbb P^5$ by $1.x_1=-x_6, 1.x_2=-x_5, 1.x_3=-x_3, 1.x_4=-x_4, 1.x_5=-x_2, 1.x_6=-x_1$ where $1$ is the non-identity element of $\mathbb Z_2$.  I need to understand the orbit space for the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on ($\mathbb P^5 -(\mathbb P^5)^{\mathbb Z_2}$) in this case. I computed the fixed locus and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ but I don't have a clear picture how the orbit space looks like. Is there a nice realization of the orbit space ? May be a bundle over something ?

Comment: I take it you're using $x_1,\cdots,x_6$ as basis elements of the $6$-dimensional vector space, and describing the lifted action of $\Bbb Z_2$ on this?

Comment: yes, that is correct. In other words $1.[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6]=[-x_6,-x_5,-x_3,-x_4,-x_2,-x_1]$.

Comment: With a change of variables, that looks like $[u_1,u_2,u_3.u_4,u_5,u_6]\mapsto [u_1,u_2,-u_3,-u_4,-u_5,-u_6]$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The 1st two variables are fixed but why does the others go to their respective negatives ?

Comment: Use the change of variables $$ \begin{array}{ll} u_1 & = e_1-e_6 \\ u_2 & = e_2-e_5 \\ u_3 & =e_3 \\ u_4 & =e_4 \\ u_5 & =e_2+e_5 \\ u_6 & =e_1+e_6 \end{array} $$ where $\{e_1,\cdots,e_6\}$ is the standard coordinate basis.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. So the fixed point set is a $\mathbb P^1$. Now although the action looks simple now I still can not figure out the orbit space for the free action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $\mathbb P^5 - \mathbb P^1$.

Comment: The fixed points in $\Bbb A^6$ are of the form $(u_1,u_2,0,0,0,0)$, but the fixed points in $\Bbb P^5$ also include those of  the form $[0,0,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6]$, so the fixed point set should be $\Bbb P^1\sqcup \Bbb P^3$ no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. How does it embed in $\mathbb P^5$ and what is the complement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the change of variables

$$ \begin{array}{ll} u_1 & = x_1-x_6 \\ u_2 & = x_2-x_5 \\ u_3 & =x_3 \\ u_4 & =x_4 \\ u_5 & =x_2+x_5 \\ u_6 & =x_1+x_6 \end{array} $$

With respect to this basis, the lifted action of the nontrivial element $g$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is given by the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(+1,+1,-1,-1,-1,-1)$. Thus, the fixed point set in $\mathbb{A}^6$ (in $u$ coordinates) is given by those vectors of the form $(u_1,u_2,0,0,0,0)$, while there are additional fixed points in $\mathbb{P}^5$ of the form $[0,0,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6]$. The first parametrizes a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$, and the second parametrizes a copy of $\mathbb{P}^3$ inside $\mathbb{P}^5$. The complement $C$ is comprsied of all $[u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6]$ in which both of $(u_1,u_2)$ and $(u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6)$ are nonzero. We then have a surjection $A\times\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^3\to C/\mathbb{Z}_2$,

$$ (a,[u_1,u_2],[u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6])\mapsto [au_1,au_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6], $$

where $A=(\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the action being $a\leftrightarrow -a$).

If the field is $\mathbb{R}$, this is $\simeq\mathbb{R}\times S^1\times \mathbb{RP}^3$. If it's $\mathbb{C}$, this is $\simeq \mathbb{R}\times S^1\times S^2\times\mathbb{CP}^3$.

Comment: Thanks, where did you get an A there ?

Comment: tem: I am still trying to figure out where does the factor A come from. The answer is correct and the dimensions match up. Could you please explain a bit ? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkShiffor Consider pairs $((u_1,u_2),(u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6))$ mod scalars. You can normalize one or the other but not both, unless you normalize both by pulling a scalar out in front.

Comment: Thanks and its clear now. How is this quotient related to the whole quotient $\mathbb P^5/{\mathbb Z_2}$ ?